# API design: HATEOAS, json, versioning, and media types

Tags: json, api, rest, hateoas

I like the REST HATEOAS concept of making your API discoverable through hyperlinks.  People like XML with ATOM format for links and you might not even need to version your API. But, I'm only doing JSON and I want to version my API and still do HATEOAS.

It seems that a best practice would be to use a vendor media type as in `application/vnd.me.v1+json` but then there is all this talk about no format for hyperlinks in JSON and things like HAL, JSON+Collecton, and Siren which have their own media type.

So, here's my confusion. First, why specify a format through media type? Why can't the inclusion of links in JSON just be a convention that clients follow? Isn't that how hm-json browser discovers links?

And, if it must be defined as a media type, does something like this work?

```
application/vnd.me.v1.hal+json
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, why specify a format through media type?

Yes, you could have a convention for the format of the links, however, any convention could only be discovered after unpacking the body of the HTTP message.  Since media types are headers, the body of the message can be accepted or rejected as an entire unit.  This makes processing requests more efficient for consumers that do not support the media types offered.

> application/vnd.me.v1.hal+json

As far as I understand, media types can be scoped to a level that fits the API you are describing.  So, you could choose to have a media type for a single representation, a group of representations that all adhere to the same service, or a single media type for the entire organization.

[This is a good SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880881/rest-media-type-explosion) considering media types:

Comment: Thanks, your explanation and link has been insightful.  In terms of the second question, if a client understands HAL and sees application/hal+json as the media type it can automatically discover links but will that same client understand and automatically discover HAL formated links when media type is application/vnd.me.v1.hal+json?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think so.  The IANA document and support standard media types.  So, I would expect those to be supported, but in the HTTP spec it doesn't seem to indicate that there is a special format to the media type (besides type/format) that a consumer could automatically understand.

Comment: Now I'm confused. So, then what is the point of hal+json to the media type?

Comment: [This blog post](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/) looks helpful.