# REST Media Type Proliferation

Tags: api, rest, content-type, api-design, media-type

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880881/rest-media-type-explosion) that seeks to address the issue of REST media-type explosion. One of the suggestions was to have a media-type that describes a collection of *anything*. So for example, we could have an `application/vnd.collection+json` which is a collection with well-defined semantics that can hold a list of references to other resources:

```
{
    "size": "3"
    "elements": [
         { "href" : "http://my.api.com/resource/1" },
         { "href" : "http://my.api.com/resource/2" },
         { "href" : "http://my.api.com/resource/3" }
     ]
}
```

I know an option to alleviate chattiness is to include embedded representations of resources. How would a "generic" media-type for lists accomplish that? Don't the semantics of the list change based on which embedded resource is inside it? This is especially relevant if embedded resources have different processing-rules (which would ideally be conveyed by the media type). Would be alright in this case to allow in-band information that describes the media type of the embedded resource? For example we could have `application/vnd.collection+json` for both links and embedded resources that do something like this:

```
{
    "size": "3"
    "element-content-type": "application/vnd.link+json" 
    "elements": [
         { "href" : "http://my.api.com/resource/1" },
         { "href" : "http://my.api.com/resource/2" },
         { "href" : "http://my.api.com/resource/3" }
     ]
}
```

and if it contains an embedded resource:

```
{
    "size": "3"
    "element-content-type": "application/vnd.resource+json" 
    "elements": [
         { 
             "id": "1"
             "name": "Cool Resource" 
         },
         { 
             "id": "2"
             "name": "Awesome Resource" 
         },
         { 
             "id": "3"
             "name": "Super Awesome Resource" 
         }
     ]
}
```

The assumption is that `application/vnd.link+json` and `application/vnd.resource+json` have been documented as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this a little bit more, and I think it is actually OK to include the content-type like that. The reason is, we *already* do this. In HTML the `script` tag has a `type` attribute that can be `application/javascript` or `application/vbscript` (for example). The provides the browser a hint as to how to process the content of that tag. Similarly, I think the content-type in the above example achieves the same purpose: it tells the client how to process the elements in the collection.

I wanted to update this answer some more. It appears that another way to do this is to use a rel. At least, this is how HAL does it. You can create a namespaced rel with a curie so that you end up resolving the rel to a URL that points to documentation about that resource. This way you have access to the documentation and that should tell you all you need to know about the resource(s).